# multi-constrainted single machine scheduling using Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

Let a set of tasks are given to machine to find a profitable ordering of tasks. Each task has profit, start and finish time. Machine is constrained in energy, memory and execution time duration. In addition a schedule will have a set of compatible tasks (no overlapping). Is there any Dynamic Programming strategy to produce a profitable schedule by considering all the constraints or condition?
I can solve three constraints (energy, memory and execution time duration) by using constraints merging and surrogate relaxation. But I can not handle no overlapping or tasks compatibility with other constraints...

Anybody please suggest a way to merge all the constraints for Dynamic Programming....

Comment: I think the problem needs some Artificial Intelligence algorithm. I wish I add artificial intelligence tag to this problem. It seems it has continuous, higher-order, preferred constraints. It is constraint search problem(CSP). And it is optimization problem too. The CSPs are related to search problem. I think for optimization CSP(knapsack problem) depth-limited-search is applicable.  Again to use dynamic programming it has to have sub-problem architecture and overlapping sub-problems.  So we need a little more detail example to discuss the correct answer.

Comment: I have already tried ILOG solver for CSP. But it consume more time. This problem is related to multi dimention knapsack problem, except compatible tasks constraint. So, I tried to solve this problem by DP.